# How to display serialize data from database and display to table i'm using laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

> saving data in my controller: is this how to save array in database? I
>   cannot find the exact code to display serialized data from database to
>   views

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $items_name = $request->destination;
        $serializedArr = serialize($items_name);

        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'tour_package_image'    =>  'required',
            'tour_package'          =>  'required',
            'rates'                 =>  'required',
            'destination'           =>  'required'
        ]);

        $itineraries = new Itinerary;
        $itineraries->destination = $serializedArr;
        $itineraries->save();

        $tour_package = new Tour;
        $tour_package->tour_types = $request->tour_package;
        $tour_package->itinerary_id = $itineraries->id;
        $tour_package->rates = $request->rates; 
        $tour_package->images = $request->file('tour_package_image')->store('tour-packages');
        $tour_package->save();

        Alert::success(' ','New Tour Packages Successfully Added!')->persistent('Close');

        return redirect('admin/add-tour-packages');


    }
```

Show function:

> i don't know if this is right

```
public function show(Tour $tour)
    {

        $title = "Tour Packages List";
        $user = User::where('id', session('user'))->first();
        $tours = Tour::all();
        return view('admin.tour-packages.tour_packages_list', compact('title','user','tours'));
    }
```

Views: displaying data

```
@foreach($tours as $tour)
                        <tr>
                          <td><img class="table-images" src="{{Storage::url($tour->images)}}" height="50" width="60"></td>
                          <td>{{$tour->tour_types}}</td>
                          <td>{{$tour->rates}}</td>
                          <td>{{unserialize($tour->Itinerary)->destination)}}</td>
                        </tr>
                      @endforeach
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: What is the output of this `$tour->Itinerary`

Comment: have yo print the array $serializedArr. Can you share the output?